# Issues with CORS in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cors, http-status-code-405

I have this App where I would like to set my custom headers in the Web.Config, alas this is not always fool proof.

```
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
```

The above set and iterations of it such as

```
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="OPTIONS,GET,PUT,DELETE,POST" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Authorization,Content-Type" />
  </customHeaders>
```

has not worked worked for me in all scenario's. As of now this setting works in about 50% of the test machines and gives `405 Method Not Allowed` in others.

The alternative is set this in `WebApiConfig.cs` and uncomment the custom headers in `Web.config`.

```
//Web API Cross origin requests - Enable
  var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
  config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Why is there so much ambiguity in this and how do I know for sure where `CORS` will work all the time? I am really interested in setting CORS on `Web.config` only as I would like the flexibility of modifying it in the deployed version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe that your 'random' issue occurs because you are not handling the preflight `Options` *requests* for `PUT` and `Delete` *verbs*.

For the two *verbs* mentioned above an extra *request* is generated, `Options`, to which `Web API` needs to respond in order to confirm that it is indeed configured to support `CORS`.

To handle this, all you need to do is send an *empty response* back. You can do this inside your actions, or you can do it globally like this:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        Response.Flush();
    }
}
```

This extra check was added to ensure that old `APIs` that were designed to accept only `GET` and `POST` requests will not be exploited. Imagine sending a `DELETE` request to an `API` designed when this *verb* didn't exist. The outcome is *unpredictable* and the results might be *dangerous*.

Also, in `web.config`, you should specify the methods instead of using `*`

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
```

Comment: Yes, this seems like the problem. The issue seems random but from what I read from your post, it seems like it may not actually be. Can you please explain the reason or that?

Comment: This extra check was added to ensure that old APIs that were configured to accept only GET and POST requests will not be exploited. Imagine sending a DELETE verb to an API designed when this verb didn't exist. The outcome is unsure and it could cause serious problems to the data behind that API.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ambiguity with CORS, you have a few cases that you need to think about

1- if you want to enable CORS for your Web APIs only use "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" library.

2- if you want to enable CORS for the whole website (including the Web APIs, SignalR, ..etc ) use "Microsoft.Owin.Cors" library.

using any library from the above 2 will definitely work and cors will be enabled, now if you want to configure the urls, you can do that from your database/config file, so when your application starts the url that you pass to the EnableCors for example can come from the database/config file, but the bottom line is to avoid adding any cors headers to the web.config.

To know to enable CORS for your Web API, you can have a look to my article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/742532/Using-Web-API-Individual-User-Account-plus-CORS-En), which enables CORS for the Web APIs and use it from AngularJS client.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this, this may help.

Even with the following startup code

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

I had to explcitly add the verbs to the Web Api action method:

```
[Route("sanity")]
[HttpOptions]
[HttpPost]
public List<PostImportView> Sanity(SanityFilter filter)
{
    ....
```

Pretty pointless and annoying